# « Stormy Daniels propose une alternative [...] » : que propose-t-elle et est-ce une « alternative » ?

Tags: emprunts, politique, connotation, faux-amis

Un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/insolite/201901/08/01-5210355-stormy-daniels-propose-une-alternative-au-discours-de-trump.php) s'intitule « Stormy Daniels propose une alternative au discours de Trump » (La Presse, 8 janvier 2019). En [français](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1127), contrairement à ce qu'on trouve en langue [anglaise](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=alternative&submit.x=0&submit.y=0), l'[*alternative*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/alternative/1) ne désigne pas chacune des possibilités qui s'offrent à quelqu'un mais bien *un choix entre deux possibilités*. Mme Daniels n'avait pas employé ce terme en langue anglaise ; elle a simplement dit que « If you're looking for anything even remotely worth watching tonight [...] » [Si vous cherchez à regarder quelque chose qui ait un vague intérêt ce soir...].

---

- Quel terme est le plus usuel pour remplacer *alternative* dans le titre de l'article ?
- Présenter ce qu'elle dit comme une *proposition d'alternative* ajoute-t-il une connotation de caractère *présomptueux* qui serait absent du propos original ; le contexte le justifie-t-il par extrapolation de « anything even remotely worth » [quelque chose qui ait un vague intérêt] ; s'agit-il d'une simple erreur ?

Comment: A headline has to be short and catchy. I can't think of a more concise one in French here. Plus, using "alternative" is justified - that's basically what she offers. Slightly ironic, no-nonsense rephrasing of a situation or public statement is very common in press headlines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Alternative*** est de plus en plus utilisé avec le sens qu'il a le plus souvent en anglais mais dans ce cas précis, on peut comprendre que Stormy Daniels propose un choix entre la prestation de Trump et la sienne. Il s'agit alors bien de la définition principale d'alternative fournie par le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/alternative)

> Permission ou obligation, le plus souvent inéluctable, de choisir entre deux propositions, deux situations, deux décisions.

Le sens élargi à chacun des choix possibles est aussi présent dans le TLFi et ne choque plus grand monde :

> Usuel, dans la lang. relâchée. Chacune des deux options d'une alternative. Choisir entre deux alternatives la moins mauvaise.

L'utilisation du mot alternative pour désigner l'une des deux options plutôt que le choix n'est d'ailleurs pas nouvelle. On la retrouve par exemple dans [ce document du XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54039534.f666) :

[image]

On peut donc difficilement attribuer à une influence de l'anglais l'origine de cet usage, aujourd'hui courant.

Curieusement, le même phénomène qui affecte le mot ***choix*** quand il signifie par métonymie l'une des options possibles n'est pas condamné.

Comment: Excellent, merci !